# Find area bounded by given curves. $y=|x|^3e^{-x^2}, |x|=a, y=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Find area bounded by given curves.

$$y=|x|^3e^{-x^2},  |x|=a,  y=0$$

Because $y\geq0$

Area = $\int_{-a}^{a}|x|^3e^{-x^2}$ = $-\int_{-a}^0x^3e^{-x^2}+\int_{0}^ax^3e^{-x^2}$

And then I get $1-\frac{1}{2}(e^{a^2}+e^{-a^2})$

answer in the book is $1-e^{-a^2}(1+a^2)$

And one question is in the step when I divided into intervals $[-a,0]$ $[0,a]$ I supposed that $a>0$ for $a<0$ need to be seperate solution?

Comment: $|x|=a\Rightarrow a\geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made some mistake.

$ \displaystyle A = -\int_{-a}^0x^3e^{-x^2} ~ dx +\int_{0}^ax^3e^{-x^2} ~ dx = 2 \int_{0}^ax^3e^{-x^2} ~ dx$

Using substitution, $y = x^2$,

$ \displaystyle A = \int_{0}^{a^2} y e^{-y} ~ dy = 1 - e^{-a^2} (1 + a^2)$

$\big[$knowing that $ \int y e^{-y} dy = - (1 + y) e^{-y} + C$. Otherwise we can use integration by parts. $\big]$